# How do I build a web app with a proper ui for my EOS.IO app?

Tags: user-interface, blockchain, eos

I want to build a browser-based user interface for eos d-app that allows the user to perform various actions like:

Input a text string to eos app
Check wallet balance and activities
transfer tokens to another person

I've seen a lot of different options (Node.js, webassembly, etc..) but I'm not sure which language or package to use in my eos d-app that is written in .cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Assembly is used in order to run a smart-contract from the blockchain. (Keep in mind that you cpp file is executed as a wasm file.)

About your gui i think that nodejs is the best option by far due to easy integrating of EOS with Nodejs

You can check this: [Integrating EOS with Nodejs](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8cjmjy/integrating_eos_with_nodejs_frontend/)

Comment: Thanks Nikos. I am following this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use EOSIO team javascript general purpose library, and integrate it with any js framework your projects requires or you are best accustomed to - https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs.
Also, there is another project you might be interested in - 
https://get-scatter.com/
( I would add this as comment on @Nikos comment, but I don't have enough reputation )